# Multiple Kinects: Global Options parameter?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I am trying to get two (2) kinects to display camera data in rviz. I run the below commands to set distinction between the kinects:

(kinect #1) roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch device_id:#1 camera:=kinect1
(Kinect #2) roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch device_id:#2 camera:=kinect2

1. Both kinects show up in rviz properly.
2. I can add two instances of the camera display type, setting them to display kinect1 and kinect2
3. When I set the "Global Options" parameter to "kinect1_link", I can see the camera from kinect1, but not kinect2; the same goes the other way around.

What do I need to do to be able to see both kinects display in rviz?

Thanks in advance!
Andrius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52635/multiple-kinects:-global-options-parameter?/) by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2013-04-02**:
Hi Andrius,
Please update if you were able to fix the issue. I am stuck in a similar situation.
Thanks,

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-12-26**:
I would also like an update on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both kinects need to be part of the same TF tree so that rviz can transform point clouds from each one into a common frame. To do this, one option is to create two static transform publishers, one that publishes map->kinect1_link and one that publishes map->kinect2_link.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-29**:
Can you elaborate on how to do this?  I'm stuck on a similar problem.

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2014-01-07**:
If you want to find the orientation of one camera w.r.t the other use ros package camera_pose_calibration. i.e. if you want the pointclouds from both cameras to be aligned properly. In case you only want to see images from both cameras at the same time, use static transfrom publisher.

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2014-01-07**:
Example for static transform publisher: define a transform from /world to kinect1_link.
define another static transform from /world to kinect2_link. use /world as Global options in rviz and you will see both camera images.
The transform can be arbitrary if you dont need the exact camera pose.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-09**:
I've been trying to use the camera_pose_calibration package with a lot of problems: http://answers.ros.org/question/115111/errors-in-camera_pose_calibration-launch-for-3-kinects/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if you are not planning to test on a sim/real robot, you can create a simple URDF model with the optical and rgb frames of each sensor connected to /base_link

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1